I need to replace old path's images to new path with the same image
I have a column Path_Image in table DBPaths :
 Path_Image          
 C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\archive\1.png
 D:\pics_back\22.jpg
 C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\archive\947141.JPG

And I have a new Path:
E:\pics2024

I want to replace all old paths with a new one without touch images , like this :
 Path_Image
 E:\pics2024\1.png
 E:\pics2024\22.jpg
 E:\pics2024\947141.JPG

The question is that possible and how I can do it , for me no idea how it could be?

Seems like you need a tutorial on SQL? If you want to modify records you use UPDATE. If you don't want to hardcode the updates you will need to use some string logic... there are many string functions available to assist with this.

It might help to reverse the string, use CHARINDEX to find the first , discard the rest, reverse again, then append what remains to E:\pics2024. https://dbfiddle.uk/OaDtdSzT

Sergey , solved it , thanks guys for all your solving too that must learn from all.

I have little experience with string functions, so the code below is just a rough idea
WITH your_table(PATH_IMAGE)AS
(  
  SELECT ' C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\archive\1.png' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D:\pics_back\22.jpg' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\archive\947141.JPG'
)
SELECT C.PATH_IMAGE,'E:\pics2024'+RIGHT(C.PATH_IMAGE,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(C.PATH_IMAGE)))
FROM your_table AS C


It's worked for me , thanks for saving me hours.

RIGHT was added in SQL Server 2008. Before 2008 you had to use combinations of SUBSTRING and REVERSE.

Thanks for all comments that I learned from and I edited the query to be:
 UPDATE DBPaths SET Path_Image = 'E:\pics2024' +  RIGHT(Path_Image, (CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(Path_Image)) )) from DBPaths 

The result will be :
 Path_Image
 E:\pics2024\1.png
 E:\pics2024\22.jpg
 E:\pics2024\947141.JPG

